# function event.preventDefault() not working in android chrome

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, event-handling

Here is a simple example of the issue I am facing: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q26C/) . 
You can not enter values into the text field on PC. The very same code does not work on android chrome. I am able to type anything into the field.

I am trying to prevent text being entered into a text box under a certain condition

Here is the function

```
function func(event, src){
    if (condition){
        alert(33);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I have used it like this:

```
<input onkeydown="func(event, $(this))" />
```

The code works perfectly on windows ie and chrome. However on chrome in android, it shows an the alert 33 but it does not prevent text from being entered. I have tried `event.stopPropagation();` and `return false` but the output is still the same(only shows the alert).

Note: I can not use `$("input").keydown()` because of some other features. So I can only use events via html .

Comment: Same behaviour without alerting anything?

Comment: same behavior as in, it gives the alert but it does not disable the key entered

Comment: does `event` expected object on Android?

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach:

HTML

```
<input id="pVal" />
```

JavaScript:

```
const inpt = getElementById('pVal')
inpt.addEventListener('textInput', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
})
```

It works in Android Chrome